# TFS releases per project overview

Tags: tfs

I'm looking for an overview in Microsoft Team Foundation Server where all projects with releases/sprints are listed in one convenient overview.

Something along the lines of

```
Project    Release   Sprint  StartDate  EndDate
Customer1  BetaTest  1       16-10      18-10
Customer6  AccTest   2       17-10      20-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view/report does not exist in TFS.  You could create it yourself either by using the TFS API to retrieve and display this information.  Or probably via a SSRS report against the TFS Data Warehouse.